# Is it unsafe to hide a power strip in a cardboard box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, fire-hazard

[image: wires in cardboard box]

In a attempt to find a solution to the multiple cables running wild in my room, I thought of hiding them into a box, but I am concerned about a possible fire hazard.

The power strip has five sockets, with the following use cases:

1. Most of the time: just the wifi router
2. Around two consecutive hours a day: wifi router, PC and screen
3. Sometimes or at night: wifi router and phone charger.

The dimensions of the box (as shown on the picture above) are 50×30×20 cm.
If that is of any relevance, I live in France.

**Is there a chance this could catch fire if I stick to these use cases? Can I also safely close the lid, which is cardboard too?**

Comment: Why not do proper cable management with Velcro?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch mostly aesthetic, but I will settle for this kind of solution if the box is a risk.

Comment: why don't you attach the power bar to the wall and then bundle up the cables?

Comment: @jsotola I could be wrong but that sounds like a more involved and less flexible option that HazardousGlitch's one.

Comment: @Alexis, it is a lot easier to manage cables if the power bar is not on the floor .... it could be attached to a desk also using some nylon cable ties ...... the other benefit is that power adapters and power cords are easier to plug and unplug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not particularly risky, but its not a fantastic idea either.

The amounts of current you are talking about pulling is not great, so heat dissipation should nor be an issue.

No one will give you a guarantee that it wont catch fire, but it us highly unlikely provided none of the cables have exposed wiring (which might short and spark).

Why not use a plastic container instead? (Assuming a cable management solution as @HazardousGlitch mentioned does not do it for you.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about the fire hazard you can line it with some cheap material like ceramic tile or clay.

- Ignition temperature of cardboard 260 C.
- Ignition temperature of wood 365 C.
- Ignition temperature of clay/ceramics 1000+ C.